# point gem branch path in gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

How to point gem branch path in gemfile.

This is what i am doing :

```
gem 'rails',     path: '/home/ubuntu/workspace/Fork/rails', :branch => 'any_of'
```

but when i run `bundle update`, it's not show any branch like sprockets-rails.

```
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0.rc4) from git://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails.git (at master) 
Using rails (4.1.0.beta) from source at /home/ubuntu/workspace/Fork/rails
```

Is there any typo?

Comment: you are using local git ? please check http://gembundler.com/v1.3/git.html

Comment: that what i am doing, gem 'rails',     path: '/home/ubuntu/workspace/Fork/rails', :branch => 'any_of' . i can do global config OR it self in gem.

Comment: you can do it by global,local and application specific cofig. you can't directly define in gem file. so set app specific config try  `bundle config --local NAME VALUE ` this will create `app/.bundle/config`

Comment: Using rails (4.1.0.beta) from git://github.com/rails/rails.git (at /home/ubuntu/workspace/Fork/rails) but i am expecting execution                                                            Using rails (4.1.0.beta) from source at /home/ubuntu/workspace/Fork/rails(at any_of)

Comment: You dont need to specify a branch really. Just ensure that the branch is checked out within the path directory.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In your app run this command.

```
bundle config local.rails /home/ubuntu/workspace/Fork/rails
```

Then in your Gemfile you specify the github source which will be overridden.

```
gem 'rails', :github => 'rails/rails', :branch => 'any_of'
```

Source: http://gembundler.com/v1.3/git.html

Comment: I done same, but bundle update showing Using rails (4.1.0.beta) from git://github.com/rails/rails.git (at /home/ubuntu/workspace/Fork/rails) , "at /home/ubuntu/workspace/Fork/rails" it supposed to be any_of.

Comment: You are saying it didn't peak the any_of branch because the outputs does not says so or you are sure it peaked from master? Can you do a test on that to make sure?

Comment: Thanks Ismael, it's working. just curious why it's not showing?

Comment: Have no idea. Maybe you should file an issue about that. It might be a bug or maybe it's just not intended to display the branch